# Too many sessions are open error, while creating connection to Sql Server Ce

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

My C# application uses *Sql Server Compact Edition* in which I got connections to the database here and there. I use this method to run `ExecuteScalar` and I use it repetitive in some point.

This is the class:

```
//_cnt & _cmd are private variables
public static object Run_ExecuteScaler(string query)
{
    object objResult;
   _cnt = new SqlCeConnection {ConnectionString = ConnectionString};

    _cmd = new SqlCeCommand
        {
            Connection = _cnt,
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
            CommandText = query
        };

    if (_cnt.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        _cnt.Open();

    objResult = _cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    _cmd.Dispose();

    if (_cnt.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        _cnt.Close();
    _cnt.Dispose();
    return objResult;
}
```

I use this line in a `foreach` loop which uses the above method to ctreate a connection to the database and run the command. It then **closes** the connection and **disposes** it.

```
var middleCat = RSSql.Run_ExecuteScaler(string.Format(
                "SELECT Implication FROM tblMiddleCategory where IDMiddleCategory='{0}'",someInt));
```

But I'm getting this error after second loop:

> Too many sessions are open

I realize that this usually happens when a connection hasn't been disposed. but I do it in my method. So Am I doing it in a wrong way?

**Update**

I changed the method to use `using` statement as @Damien_The_Unbeliever offered:

```
public static object Run_ExecuteScaler(string query)
{
    object objResult = null;
    using (_cnt = new SqlCeConnection( ConnectionString))
    {
        _cmd = new SqlCeCommand
        {
            Connection = _cnt,
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
            CommandText = query
        };
        if (_cnt.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            _cnt.Open();
        objResult = _cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    return objResult;
}
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You do dispose in your method if nothing *throws an exception*. You should prefer to use `using` statements which guarantee disposal no matter how control leaves your method.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I used `using` as u offered, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Try out this solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bf489f8d-97da-40b0-8ba0-a11c6c783ea1/too-many-open-sessions?forum=sqlce

Comment: The try catch finally helps. you should close the connection in finally block. this block will execute anyway.

Comment: You can make connection as parameter to ExecuteScalar method, then make in main program one connection and give it to the method everytime you want to use database. Then you will have one connection (per user, if anyone else is going to use your app)